# How can I change the side of all (or single) pages of a twoside book?

Tags: horizontal-alignment, double-sided, book-design

My book's first page is righthanded the second page is lefthanded the third righthanded and so on but I want it of the form: first page to be lefthanded the second page to be righthanded the third lefthanded ...
Do you know how to do it? 
Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: Can you please provide your source code for more clarity

Comment: What `\documentclass` are you using?

Comment: This should be easy with the memoir document class.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the memoir class:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openleft]{memoir}
\begin{document}
    First page is a verso (left-side) page.

    \newpage
    Second page is a recto (right-side) page.

\end{document}
```

If you want to stick to book, article or report documentclass, you have to redefine \cleardoublepage:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{book}
    \makeatletter
    \renewcommand*\cleardoublepage{\clearpage\if@twoside
      \ifodd\c@page \hbox{}\newpage\if@twocolumn\hbox{}%
      \newpage\fi\fi\fi}
    \makeatother
\begin{document}
        First page is a verso (left-side) page.

        \newpage
        Second page is a recto (right-side) page.
\end{document}
```